# Need help with a grammar question about prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Is “to” in the following examples a preposition, or does it act as part of the verb (to obtain, to sign, to complete)? Many thanks!

▻ I finally managed to obtain a copy of the report.
▻ Both governments have agreed to sign the treaty.
▻ You're allowed half an hour to complete the test.

Comment: I don't think #3 fits in the other two verb patterns.

Comment: That dupe has no accepted answer, and the only answer it has is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

A preposition is always followed by a noun or a pronoun:

> I went to *the store*.
>   I spoke to *your father*.

---

In some cases, the infinitive form of a verb *acts* as a noun:

From [Daily Grammar](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-220-Noun-Infinitives.htm):

> *To eat* is fun. (subject)
>   I like *to eat*. (direct object)
>   A fun thing is *to eat*. (predicate nominative)
>   My hope, *to travel*, never happened. (appositive)
>   I want nothing but *to save*. (object of preposition)

In the last example sentence, the preposition is actually *but* (being used in the sense of *except*), which is then followed by the infinitive *to save* that's acting as a noun.

---

In the example sentences in the question, all three infinitive verbs are being used as verbs; they describe actual actions.

In short, all of the sentences are using *to* verbally, not prepositionally.

Comment: What does it mean to "use *to* verbally"? Why are you calling infinitives nouns? They never are. They are verbs. That's why you it’s possible for you to speak eloquently with an adverb, and why it is impossible for you to speak *eloquent with an adjective. Infinitive clauses are non-finite verbs. That doesn't mean they cannot serve in NP roles. But they're still verb clauses.

Comment: To say that prepositions are always followed by a noun or pronoun is simply untrue. They take a range of complements comparable to verbs including PPs e.g. _I Stayed **until after lunch**._  / AdvPs e.g. _It won't last **for long**._ / Clauses e.g. _I left **because I was tired**_.